# How to connect Crystal Reports 9 to MySQL database in Windows 10

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to connect MySQL database to Crystal Reports 9 in Windows 10, but I get this error.

```
Query Engine Error: 'Cannot find DSN in connection string'
```

[image: The error message that I receive is tagged here]

Comment: Are you using the DNS or the hostname of the server for the data source field?

Comment: I don't Know if i have got your question clear but i'm using localhost otherwise sorry for the delay.